# Npm install of PhantomJS hangs up

Tags: node.js, package, npm, phantomjs

Any time I've tried to install a package.json via npm that contains phantomJS, or a package that uses it as a dependency, the installation hangs up on the phantomJS install.  Haven't a clue what would cause this, any ideas?

```
>$ npm install
|
> phantomjs@1.9.7-10 install c:\Users\user\application\node_modules\grunt-mo
cha\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js
\
```

It just stays there indefinitely (with the last slash spinning)

The verbose output:

```
    npm info install sntp@0.2.4 into c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phan
    tomjs\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk
    npm info install cryptiles@0.2.2 into c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules
    \phantomjs\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk
    npm info install boom@0.4.2 into c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phan
    tomjs\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk
    npm info installOne hoek@0.9.1
    npm info installOne sntp@0.2.4
    npm info installOne cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm info installOne boom@0.4.2
    npm info c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\reque
    st\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\hoek unbuild
    npm info c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\reque
    st\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp unbuild
    npm info c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\reque
    st\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\cryptiles unbuild
    npm info c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\reque
    st\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\boom unbuild
    npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\hoek\0.9.1\packa
    ge.tgz
    npm verb lock tar://c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_mo
    dules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\hoek C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roam
    ing\npm-cache\863dbeb6-e-modules-hawk-node-modules-hoek.lock
    npm verb lock tar://C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\hoek\0.9.1\packa
    ge.tgz C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\50375b14-npm-cache-hoek-0-9-1
    -package-tgz.lock
    npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sntp\0.2.4\packa
    ge.tgz
    npm verb lock tar://c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_mo
    dules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roam
    ing\npm-cache\8fd8d464-e-modules-hawk-node-modules-sntp.lock
    npm verb lock tar://C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sntp\0.2.4\packa
    ge.tgz C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\8e173eaf-npm-cache-sntp-0-2-4
    -package-tgz.lock
    npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cryptiles\0.2.2\
    package.tgz
    npm verb lock tar://c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_mo
    dules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\cryptiles C:\Users\Nick\AppData
    \Roaming\npm-cache\ea16e82e-ules-hawk-node-modules-cryptiles.lock
    npm verb lock tar://C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cryptiles\0.2.2\
    package.tgz C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\46f6a6ad-ache-cryptiles-
    0-2-2-package-tgz.lock
    npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\boom\0.4.2\packa
    ge.tgz
    npm verb lock tar://c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_mo
    dules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\boom C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roam
    ing\npm-cache\12a79658-e-modules-hawk-node-modules-boom.lock
    npm verb lock tar://C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\boom\0.4.2\packa
    ge.tgz C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\9ddfd014-npm-cache-boom-0-4-2
    -package-tgz.lock
    npm info preinstall cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm info preinstall ctype@0.5.2
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\cryptiles
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\cryptiles
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\hawk\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm verb linkBins cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm verb linkMans cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm verb rebuildBundles cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm info install cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\ctype
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\ctype
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\http-signature\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff ctype@0.5.2
    npm verb linkBins ctype@0.5.2
    npm verb linkMans ctype@0.5.2
    npm verb rebuildBundles ctype@0.5.2
    npm info postinstall cryptiles@0.2.2
    npm info install ctype@0.5.2
    npm info preinstall sntp@0.2.4
    npm info postinstall ctype@0.5.2
    npm info preinstall boom@0.4.2
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\http-signature
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb linkBins http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb linkMans http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb rebuildBundles http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'asn1', 'assert-plus', 'ctype' ]
    npm info install http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\hawk\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff sntp@0.2.4
    npm verb linkBins sntp@0.2.4
    npm verb linkMans sntp@0.2.4
    npm verb rebuildBundles sntp@0.2.4
    npm info install sntp@0.2.4
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm info postinstall http-signature@0.10.0
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\boom
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\boom
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\hawk\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff boom@0.4.2
    npm verb linkBins boom@0.4.2
    npm verb linkMans boom@0.4.2
    npm verb rebuildBundles boom@0.4.2
    npm info postinstall sntp@0.2.4
    npm info install boom@0.4.2
    npm info postinstall boom@0.4.2
    npm info preinstall hoek@0.9.1
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\hoek
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\hoek
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\hawk\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff hoek@0.9.1
    npm verb linkBins hoek@0.9.1
    npm verb linkMans hoek@0.9.1
    npm verb rebuildBundles hoek@0.9.1
    npm info install hoek@0.9.1
    npm info postinstall hoek@0.9.1
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\hawk
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\hawk
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff hawk@1.0.0
    npm verb linkBins hawk@1.0.0
    npm verb linkMans hawk@1.0.0
    npm verb rebuildBundles hawk@1.0.0
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'boom', 'cryptiles', 'hoek', 'sntp' ]
    npm info install hawk@1.0.0
    npm info postinstall hawk@1.0.0
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream
    npm verb etag delayed-stream from cache
    npm info install delayed-stream@0.0.5 into c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_mo
    dules\phantomjs\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combine
    d-stream
    npm info installOne delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm info c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\reque
    st\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stre
    am unbuild
    npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\delayed-stream\0
    .0.5\package.tgz
    npm verb lock tar://c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_mo
    dules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\d
    elayed-stream C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\d068bb68-ream-node-mod
    ules-delayed-stream.lock
    npm verb lock tar://C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\delayed-stream\0
    .0.5\package.tgz C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\916573b0-delayed-st
    ream-0-0-5-package-tgz.lock
    npm info preinstall delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modul
    es\delayed-stream
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delaye
    d-stream
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\form-data\\node_modules\\combined-stream\\
    node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb linkBins delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb linkMans delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb rebuildBundles delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm info install delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm info postinstall delayed-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules\\form-data\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb linkBins combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb linkMans combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb rebuildBundles combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'delayed-stream' ]
    npm info install combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm info postinstall combined-stream@0.0.5
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request\node_modules\form-data
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request\node_modules\form-data
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules\\request\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff form-data@0.1.4
    npm verb linkBins form-data@0.1.4
    npm verb linkMans form-data@0.1.4
    npm verb rebuildBundles form-data@0.1.4
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'async', 'combined-stream' ]
    npm info install form-data@0.1.4
    npm info postinstall form-data@0.1.4
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\nod
    e_modules\request
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
    \request
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\phantomjs\
    \node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff request@2.36.0
    npm verb linkBins request@2.36.0
    npm verb linkMans request@2.36.0
    npm verb rebuildBundles request@2.36.0
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'aws-sign2',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'forever-agent',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'form-data',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'hawk',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'http-signature',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'json-stringify-safe',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'mime',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'node-uuid',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'oauth-sign',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'qs',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'tough-cookie',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'tunnel-agent' ]
    npm info install request@2.36.0
    npm info postinstall request@2.36.0
    npm verb about to build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs
    npm info build c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomjs
    npm verb linkStuff [ false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   false,
    npm verb linkStuff   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules' ]
    npm info linkStuff phantomjs@1.9.7-10
    npm verb linkBins phantomjs@1.9.7-10
    npm verb link bins [ { phantomjs: './bin/phantomjs' },
    npm verb link bins   'c:\\Users\\Nick\\extensionTest\\node_modules\\.bin',
    npm verb link bins   false ]
    npm verb linkMans phantomjs@1.9.7-10
    npm verb rebuildBundles phantomjs@1.9.7-10
    npm verb rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'adm-zip',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'kew',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'mkdirp',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'ncp',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'npmconf',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'request',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'rimraf',
    npm verb rebuildBundles   'which' ]
    npm info install phantomjs@1.9.7-10


    > phantomjs@1.9.7-10 install c:\Users\Nick\extensionTest\node_modules\phantomj
    s
    > node install.js

    \
```

Comment: Add 

     --verbose 

and post the output here

Comment: @MarcodeJongh, hopefully that means more to someone here than it does to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem as well on my Windows 7 box. I solved it by uninstalling my existing installation of PhantomJS and removing the reference to it from the PATH variable. Then I cleaned my npm cache (npm cache clean) and ran npm install again. This time the npm install operation completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by running

`npm cache verify`